# How to use an array to fill the title text

Tags: xcode, swift4

I've created a customized keyboard using UIView. I'm trying to auto-fill the letters using a for loop but with no success.

```
func initializeSubviews() {
    let xibFileName = "keyboardView" // xib extension not included b
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
          setKeyboardText()
}

@IBOutlet var keyboardLetters: [myKeyboardBtn]!

func setKeyboardText() {
    let str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    let characterArray = Array(str)

    for (Index, key) in keyboardLetters.enumerated() {
        key.titleLabel?.text = String(characterArray[Index])
    }
    // [a,b,c,d,...]

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple

```
"To set the actual text of the label, use setTitle(_:for:) 

(button.titleLabel.text does not let you set the text)."
```